# oracle report builder 6i - sql query code in Data Model

Tags: oracle, database-design, report, builder

I'm Vijetha, 
I'm working on Reports 6i & am very new to it. I have the following query.

In the front_end, in Reports Parameter, When the user clicks on the 'run' button, it will ask for START_DATE & END_DATE inputs.

If the user gives START_DATE & END_DATE or does not give input, 
no matter what the code should execute. `enter code here`
1)If the user gives start_date & end_date ,
then only those reports with that particular given date should be displayed.
2)If the user does not give start_date & end_date,

### then all reports of all dates must be displayed.

so i have to use 2 select statements. they are:

1)`SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE TO_CHAR(DUE_DATE, 'MMYYYY') BETWEEN :START_DATE AND :END_DATE;`

### 2)`SELECT * FROM T1;`

I want something like the below:

--

```
if start_date=null & end_date=null,
then SELECT * FROM T1;
else 
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE TO_CHAR(DUE_DATE, 'MMYYYY') BETWEEN :START_DATE AND :END_DATE;
end if;
```

### --

But the above code does not work since the SQL Query Statement in Data Model should be coded inside a select statement,hence it must be inside a select statement, like below:

--

```
select[
if start_date=null & end_date=null,
then SELECT * FROM T1;
else 
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE TO_CHAR(DUE_DATE, 'MMYYYY') BETWEEN :START_DATE AND :END_DATE;
end if;
] from t1;
```

--

---

I tried NVL  & DECODE , but it does not work for multiple values.

Please help me with the above coding part in the Query Dialog(SQL Query Statement) in Data Model.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your not stored selected value in a pl/sql variable.AS we know that we need to stored selected value in a perticular variable.You may use scalar or record type  variable to stored data.